# Unable to create new user

Tags: android, kotlin

When i am trying to create new account, The create account button is not triggering in android studio and not going to next activity, Even there is no error message displaying at screen. Please help me to resolve this issue.

This is in Kotlin version and how to display error message when an user doesnt fill any of the fields mentioned below.

```
class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity( ) {

var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
var mDatabase: DatabaseReference? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()


    createaccountET.setOnClickListener {


        val name = accountdisplaynameET.text.toString().trim()
        val email = registeremailET.text.toString().trim()
        val password = registerpasswordET.text.toString().trim()
        val reenterpassword = reenterpasswordET.text.toString().trim()
        val Mobile = mobilenumberET.text.toString().trim()
        val date = dateofbirthET.text.toString().trim()
        val gender = genderET.text.toString().trim()

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && name.length > 3 ||
                !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches() ||
                !TextUtils.isEmpty(Mobile) && Mobile.length != 10 ||
                !TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && password.length < 4 && password.length > 10 ||
                !TextUtils.isEmpty(reenterpassword) && reenterpassword.length < 4 && reenterpassword.length > 10 && reenterpassword != password ||
                !TextUtils.isEmpty(date) ||
                !TextUtils.isEmpty(gender)) {

            createAccount(email, password,name,Mobile, date,gender )

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill out the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()

        }
    }

}


fun createAccount(email: String, password: String, name: String, Mobile: String, date: String, gender: String) {

    mAuth!!.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {

                task: Task<AuthResult> ->

                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val currentUser = mAuth!!.currentUser
                    val userId = currentUser!!.uid

                    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                            .child("Users").child(userId)

                    /*
                        Users Profile Information

                     */

                    val userObject = HashMap<String, String>()
                    userObject.put("display_name", name)
                    userObject.put("Mobile", Mobile)
                    userObject.put("date", date)
                    userObject.put("email", email)
                    userObject.put("gender", gender)
                    userObject.put("image", "default")
                    userObject.put("thumb_image", "default")

                    mDatabase!!.setValue(userObject).addOnCompleteListener {

                        task: Task<Void> ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {

                            Toast.makeText(this, "User Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show()
                            val purchaseIntent = Intent(this, PurchaseActivity::class.java)
                                    startActivity(purchaseIntent)
                            finish()

                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(this@RegisterActivity, "User Not Created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show()
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


}
}
```

Comment: Check the exception with task.getException
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/tasks/Task)

Comment: I tried but same issue.

Comment: What have you tried? Share with us what exception you are receiving.

Comment: The CreateAccount button not working when i m press that one.